# Printing OSGI bundle classpath?

Tags: eclipse, classpath, osgi

In a normal java application its possible to print the content of the classpath with:

```
String ss = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
System.out.println(ss);
```

But how do I print the classpath of an OSGI bundle created using the eclipse PDE wizard? In the activator its possible to get the current bundle like:

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);
    plugin = this;

```
Bundle b  = context.getBundle();
 // java doc: This bundle's class loader is not used to search for entries. 
b.findEntries(path, filePattern, recurse)
```

But the javadoc says that the findEntries does NOT use the class loader. Is there any simple way to see/prints what is on the current bundle's classpath?

Comment: First question is: why do you want to do that? There is no real notion of a classpath for a bundle, merely a set of classes that are accessible.

Comment: Just to be clear: there is a bundle header known as Bundle-ClassPath (osgi core 3.2.1.4), but given your "java.class.path" example, this is probably not what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have indicated there is really no such thing as a "bundle classpath" - that's the whole point of OSGi. :)

What you can do is:

- look at your bundle's headers to see which packages it imports, and whether they are required or mandatory
- use PackageAdmin to find bundles that export packages with a given name

However AFAIK PackageAdmin is deprecated and there will be a new/extended mechanism to work with bundle wiring in 4.3.

It seems like your real motivation for this is classpath scanning to find & load resources. The fact that this is not easily possible is a side effect of enforcing module boundaries: you can't have a fence and at the same time allow anyone to walk on the lawn.
There was a plan for a standard service that scans bundles on behalf of a client, but that seems to have been withdrawn (not sure why - maybe as consequence of the new 4.3 stuff).

Comment: Stating PackageAdmin is deprecated is pushing it, as it's definitely not deprecated yet in the latest released specs (R4.2).