# Felix How to get list of all dependent bundles from the updated bundle

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, apache-felix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the dependent bundles in Eclipse at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153421/find-the-dependent-bundles-in-eclipse-at-runtime)

How to get list of all dependent bundles from the updated bundle?
For example, situation when some application loaded same bundles.
In one time I will update one bundle.
How can I get all bundles which depend on the updated bundle?
This is necessary in order to restart all bundles which depend on the updated bundle, so they can see a new object of the updated bundle.
Sorry my bad English.
Best regards, Arthur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [FrameworkWiring.getDependencyClosure](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/FrameworkWiring.html#getDependencyClosure%28java.util.Collection%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

if you see [Find the dependent bundles in Eclipse at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153421/find-the-dependent-bundles-in-eclipse-at-runtime):

akr writes:

> There is no easy way to determine the dependency. The best way is to go through the PackageAdmin interface. See the OSGi spec for PackageAdmin and getImportingBundles in particular: http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/packageadmin/ExportedPackage.html#getImportingBundles()
>
> You need to determine for all installed bundles, which one exports one or more packages >that your bundle is importing. The easiest way to achieve this is to call PackageAdmin.getExportedPackages(Bundle bundle) with bundles = null. This returns an array >of all exported packages. You then need to iterate of this array and call ExportPackage.getImportingBundles().

Comment: Well, I understand.
As far as I understand it, if I updated a bundle, I need to restart all bundles, that uses updated bundle? It is necessary to bundles that use the updated bundle began to use the new object of updated bundle? Before restarting all the other bundles that use the updated bundle will use the old object of the updated bundle?

Comment: PackageAdmin is deprecated. I would advise using FrameworkWiring.getDependencyClosure instead.