# Felix how to use FrameworkWiring.getDependencyClosure

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, apache-felix

I am trying to get depends for each bundle.
In this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986935/felix-how-to-get-list-of-all-dependent-bundles-from-the-updated-bundle) I was advised to use `FrameworkWiring.getDependencyClosure`, 
but I can't understand how to initialize class, `FrameworkWiring.getDependencyClosure` - it's interface.
Is there any implementations of this interface in felix?

And second question:
I have found

```
BundleWiringImpl getRequirements(null);
```

but I can't initialize

```
BundleWiringImpl testObject = new BundleWiringImpl();
```

NetBeans show error:

```
constructor BundleWiringImpl in class BundleWiringImpl cannot be applied to given types;
  required: Logger,Map,StatefulResolver,BundleRevisionImpl,List<BundleRevision>,List<BundleWire>,Map<String,BundleRevision>,Map<String,List<BundleRevision>>
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

How to get deps? :)
May be any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh. Did you read the [javadoc](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/FrameworkWiring.html) for the FrameworkWiring type?

`The framework wiring object for the framework can be obtained by calling bundle.adapt(FrameworkWiring.class) on the system bundle. Only the system bundle can be adapted to a FrameworkWiring object.`

Comment: Why it can be adapt only for the system bundle? Why I can't call it from other bundle? May be I want to make one bundle with update logic, for simplify updating of the Updater bundle(self updating of the updater bundle).

Comment: Because that is the way it was designed. FrameworkWiring is about the whole framework and the system bundle is a synonym for the framework. You can easily get the system bundle object from any BundleContext: ```context.getBundle(0)```.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for response. But when I try to do something like this http://pastebin.com/SzZaTRLL I get compilation error http://pastebin.com/Hi6Kb2QL