# Error on compiling bundle with Maven on context.getBundle(0).adapt(FrameworkWiring.class).getDependencyClosure(bundles)

Tags: java, maven-2, osgi, bundle, apache-felix

On bundle compiling with code

```
    package ihtika2.mainform;

import com.google.code.ihtika.Vars.Ini;
import ihtika2.mainform.service.MainFormInterface;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.InvalidSyntaxException;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.framework.wiring.FrameworkWiring;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        props.put("Funct", "MainForm");
        context.registerService(MainFormInterface.class.getName(), new MainForm(), props);

        ServiceReference[] refs = context.getServiceReferences(
                MainFormInterface.class.getName(), "(Funct=MainForm)");
        if (refs == null) {
            System.out.println("Not Found MainForm on start");
        } else {
            MainFormInterface MainForm = (MainFormInterface) context.getService(refs[0]);
            MainForm.sendContext(context);
            MainForm.showWindow();
        }

        int x = 0;
        for (Bundle qqq : context.getBundles()) {
            if (x < 1) {
                HashSet<Bundle> bundles;
                bundles = new HashSet<Bundle>();
                bundles.add(qqq);
                HashSet<Bundle> depends = (HashSet<Bundle>) context.getBundle(0).adapt(FrameworkWiring.class).getDependencyClosure(bundles);
                System.out.println("---");
                System.out.println(qqq.getSymbolicName());
                System.out.println("+++");
                for (Bundle depends1 : depends) {
                    System.out.println(depends1.getSymbolicName());
                }
            }
                x++;
        }
```

I get error

```
cd C:\Art\Dropbox\OpenSource\MyGIT\ihtika\Sources\Bundles\I_MainForm; JAVA_HOME=C:\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_06 "\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans Dev 201208160001\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\"" clean install
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building I_MainForm OSGi Bundle 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

[clean:clean]
Deleting C:\Art\Dropbox\OpenSource\MyGIT\ihtika\Sources\Bundles\I_MainForm\target

[resources:resources]
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 1 resource

[compiler:compile]
Compiling 5 source files to C:\Art\Dropbox\OpenSource\MyGIT\ihtika\Sources\Bundles\I_MainForm\target\classes
-------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
ihtika2/mainform/Activator.java:[38,109] error: cannot find symbol
1 error
-------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.886s
Finished at: Tue Aug 21 12:21:25 MSK 2012
Final Memory: 10M/25M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project I_MainForm: Compilation failure
\Art\Dropbox\OpenSource\MyGIT\ihtika\Sources\Bundles\I_MainForm\src\main\java\ihtika2\mainform\Activator.java:[38,109] error: cannot find symbol
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Please advice me, how to compile this code? 
I use apache-maven-2.2.1, jdk1.7.0_06, compiling for the 1.6 code (setting in NetBeans project ).
What interesting - NetBeans doesn't show error on this string (Activator.java:[38,109]) and consider this code correct.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the `FrameworkWiring` class that is not being found (based on the line number and your snippet above). Perhaps you should check your POM to ensure the relevant dependency is listed (I believe `org.osgi:core`) and that it is associated with the `compile` phase. Perhaps post your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Here is my pom http://pastebin.com/FqVRJGvW . In the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034070/felix-how-to-use-frameworkwiring-getdependencyclosure BJ Hargrave adviced to me call the context.getBundle(0) from the some bundle...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about osgi to advise further, but I find the usage of the `provided` scope interesting. This means you expect the dependency to be provided at runtime. I would imagine that investigating this in further detail may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in the Felix 4.0.3 and org.osgi.core (4.3.0) jars bundles from Central Maven repo.

I guess they are outdated.

As far as I understand it, except Osgi version (4.3) has also revision.

Probably the library at the central Maven repository outdated.

The solution - download and compile the source from

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/trunk/ framework.

Ie - after source download, in the folder with sources:

cd framework

mvn install

It's command will compile and install Felix to your local Maven repo. After this you can use new Felix's bundle (SNAPSHOT) instead the bundles from the Central Maven repo.

Sorry my bad English.

Comment: You can answer yourself; you've just done so. In fact [it's encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) so please provide a detailed answer to your problem. You may even get upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use osgi.core version 4.3 or higher. The FrameworkWiring type was introduced in osgi.core 4.3. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osgi/org.osgi.core/4.3.0

Apache Felix 4.0 added support for osgi.core 4.3. http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/09/felix-400